# Diagram.net: Decoded drawio file

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I created an empty diagram with a simple rectangle in diagram.net and saved the result. When I'm looking at the saved xml file I get:

```
<mxfile host="Electron"
    modified="2021-08-18T07:30:10.487Z"
    agent="5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) draw.io/14.6.13 Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Electron/12.0.7 Safari/537.36"
    etag="vJFYwEsdJsI7903eVX9u"
    version="14.6.13"
    type="device">
<diagram id="zP4AhNJyU0dJ9cslGBI6"
        name="Seite-1">jZJNb4MwDIZ/DUekEFrUXce69TJpEtN2zohLIgWC0tBAf/3CcPhQVWmnOI8/4rx2lOZ1/2ZYK941BxVRwvsofYkopSSj/hjJMJEkOSCpjOTIFlDIGyAkSDvJ4bIJtForK9stLHXTQGk3jBmj3TbsrNX21ZZVcAeKkql7+i25FRPdE7LwE8hKhJeT7Gny1CwEY+hFMK7dCqXHKM2N1nay6j4HNaoXdJnyXh9458YMNPY/Cdfm80Tc7ibOcfwB5sB/vmgcZL4y1eGPsVs7BAmM7hoOYxUSpc9OSAtFy8rR6/zUPRO2Vv6WeBPLgbHQP2w0mb/vFwd0DdYMPiQk7LEp3JldaNItA0iCqmIlfoaM4cyrufQiizdQmXBdJvDnWy1yevwF</diagram>
```

The problem is when I would like to add this file under version control with git, this hash? changes every time when changing something, but from the file it self it is not visible what changed. Do anybody know why not a more readable structure is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 20.3.0 (and probably above) of draw.io in the GUI under (File->Settings) an option to disable the compression exists. After applying it looks fine.